# Simplest or most Pythonic way to exclude rows in a DataFrame based on a list of regex patterns?

Tags: python, pandas

I know I can exclude rows like so:

```
df = df[ ~df['B'].str.contains(<regex_pattern>) ]
```

But what is the simplest or most Pythonic way to exclude rows from a list of regex patterns? Something like the following would be fine:

```
df = exclude_rows(dataframe, list_of_regex_pats)
```

(Where df would be passed in as 'dataframe'.)

How can this be done with DataFrame.drop? Or is this a problem that would call for a recursive function?

Comment: You could try combining the list with regex `OR` operator `|` ...`df[ ~df['B'].str.contains('|'.join(list_of_regex_pats))]` ?

Comment: From past experience, this kind of thing can get nasty on a large database. There's no way to index the string data on what patterns it might match. If you keep the number of records small, then nevermind.

Comment: _But what is the simplest or most Pythonic way to exclude rows from a list of regex patterns? _ I'm confused, isn't that what the first code snippet is doing?

Answer (score 0):

```
def drop_from_patterns(dataframe, column, regex_pattern_list):
    dfcopy = dataframe.copy()
    for pattern in regex_pattern_list:
        dfcopy.drop(dfcopy[ dfcopy[column].str.contains(pattern, case=False) ].index, inplace=True)
    return dfcopy
```